# × TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

So I'm getting this error and I don't get why I used the same hook and method on the profile file and it's working just fine but with the feed it's different and I don't know why.

I'm trying to get the username of the person that created the post, I only managed it to get the username of the current user logged in but not the user that made the post

[image]

The code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  Button,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useAllPosts } from "../../hooks/Posts";
import { useUser } from "../../hooks/Users";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  avatar: {
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  text: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 15,
    fontStyle: "bold",
  },
});
function Feed(props) {
  const user = useUser(props.route.params.uid);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const posts = useAllPosts(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.root}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={1}
        horizontal={false}
        data={posts}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.containerImage}>
            <Image
              style={styles.image}
              key={item.downloadURL + `?${new Date()}`}
              source={{ uri: item.downloadURL }}
            />
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Avatar className={classes.avatar}></Avatar>
              <Typography className={classes.text}>{user?.name}</Typography>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.containerInfo}>{item.caption}</Text>
            <Divider />
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
  },

  containerInfo: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  // containerGallery: {
  //   flex: 1,
  // },
  containerImage: {
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  image: {
    resizeMode: "cover",
    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
  },
});

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
  following: store.userState.following,
  users: store.usersState.users,
  usersLoaded: store.usersState.usersLoaded,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Feed);
```

Comment: how did you pass the uid to params?

Comment: @Mohammednaji I made a custom hook if this is what you mean.

Comment: Not that what I meant, I suppose you used `navigation.navigate` to navigate to this screen , can you show me how you called this function `navigation.navigate`

Comment: @Mohammednaji Ok  so this is my first project in React and with Firebase and I don't think that I’m understanding this right, but let's try. I have a navigation to this screen, but it's not in the Feed file. And I didn't use navigation.navigate for that. I used a drawer navigator for this.  What I don't get is what has the navigation to do with the error ?